# Challenging Recursion Question - Tree Nodes Representing Processes

Tags: c, recursion, tree

Thank you for reading this thread. I have a challenging question regarding using tree nodes to represent system processes.

Below is what my code has to print out when the tree nodes of the below processes are already connected like below,

1000

  1001
    
    100101
      
      10010101
         
        1001010101

  100102
      
    10010201

  1002

  1003

  1004

As you can see, 1000 is the root process, it has 4 child processes, 1001, 1002, 1003 and 1004. Processes 100101 is child of 1001, 10010101 is child process of 100101 and 1001010101 is child process of 10010101.

Despite root having 4 child processes, to get from root to the first child process, it is root->child_node. Child process 1001 has "next" process of 1002, and 1002 has next process 1003 and it has 1004 as 1003's next process. Therefore, to at to each child process on the same level, it has to go from one child process to the next child process using next_node.

Below is the result my code generates. Each process, such as 1000, is a TreeNode. Right now, my code can print from 1000 to 1001010101, such as below,

1000

  1001
    
    100101
      
      10010101
         
        1001010101

However, my current issue is how do I handle the next (neighboring node), such as 1001 and 1002 are neighbors because 1001's next_node is 1002.

// Tree Node.

```
struct TreeNode {
    pid_t pid;
    char *name;
    struct TreeNode *child_node;     // A list of child processes
    struct TreeNode *next_node;    // A link to the next sibling processes.
```

};

// My print_processes method.

```
void print_processes(struct TreeNode *root, int space_level, int level_limit) {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < space_level; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("  ");
    }

    printf("%d: %s\n", root->pid, root->name);

    struct TreeNode *node;

    while ((node = root->child_node) != NULL && level_limit != 0) {
        print_processes(node, space_level + 1, level_limit - 1);

    }

    //printf("hoho");
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

struct TreeNode *root = malloc (sizeof (struct TreeNode));
root->pid = 1000;
root->name = "sshd";
root->child_node = NULL;
root->next_node = NULL;

struct TreeNode *c1 = malloc (sizeof (struct TreeNode));
c1->pid = 1001;
c1->name = "sshd";
c1->child_node = NULL;
c1->next_node = NULL;

struct TreeNode *c2 = malloc (sizeof (struct TreeNode));
c2->pid = 1002;
c2->name = "bash";
c2->child_node = NULL;
c2->next_node = NULL;

struct TreeNode *c3 = malloc (sizeof (struct TreeNode));
c3->pid = 1003;
c3->name = "sshd";
c3->child_node = NULL;
c3->next_node = NULL;

struct TreeNode *c4 = malloc (sizeof (struct TreeNode));
c4->pid = 1004;
c4->name = "sshd";
c4->child_node = NULL;
c4->next_node = NULL;

struct TreeNode *c5 = malloc (sizeof (struct TreeNode));
c5->pid = 1005;
c5->name = "bash";
c5->child_node = NULL;
c5->next_node = NULL;

struct TreeNode *n1 = malloc (sizeof (struct TreeNode));
n1->pid = 1011;
n1->name = "bash";
n1->child_node = NULL;
n1->next_node = NULL;

c4->child_node = c5;
c3->child_node = c4;
c2->child_node = c3;
c1->child_node = c2;
c1->next_node = n1;
root->child_node = c1;

print_processes(root, 0, 3);

return 0;
```

}

Again, below is what my code has to generate in Terminal.

1000

  1001
    
    100101
      
      10010101
         
        1001010101

  100102
      
    10010201

  1002

  1003

  1004

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: The `exit(0)` in the `print_processes()` function means you can't complete the tree.  Remove it!  (That isn't very challenging, you know.)  You probably also need to add a call `if (root->next != 0) print_processes(root->next, space_level, level_limit);` in place of the `exit(0);`.  Also, since your printing appears to include a PID, a colon and a name, it is not remotely clear how it should be modified to produce what you request.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I have modified the tree structure, sorry for the confusion and thank you for your reply. But how do I get to the neighboring processes, which accesses from child process' next_node data?

Comment: Please provide an initialized data structure that needs to be printed — making an MCVE ([MCVE])/

Comment: That `while` loop will be infinite because the condition never changes. You need to loop over the siblings with something like `node = node->next` until `node` is null.

Comment: Hi All, I have added the main function. However, this structure is a bit different. Root has child c1, which as child c2, which has child c3, which has child c4 and finally it has child c5. Process c1's next_node is n1. Currently, my code cannot print out n1's branch.

Comment: Hi @interjay, thank you for your input. Where would I put node = node->next? Inside the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify and extend `print_processes()` quite a lot, and definitely make the `main()` function a lot shorter too:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct TreeNode
{
    int    pid;
    char  *name;
    struct TreeNode *child_node;     // A list of child processes
    struct TreeNode *next_node;    // A link to the next sibling processes.
};

static
void print_processes(struct TreeNode *root, int space_level, int level_limit)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < space_level; i++)
        printf("  ");

    printf("%d: %s\n", root->pid, root->name);

    if (root->child_node != NULL && level_limit > 0)
        print_processes(root->child_node, space_level + 1, level_limit - 1);
    if (root->next_node != NULL)
        print_processes(root->next_node, space_level, level_limit);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct TreeNode n1   = { 1011, "bash",   NULL, NULL };
    struct TreeNode c5   = { 1005, "bash",   NULL, NULL };
    struct TreeNode c4   = { 1004, "sshd-3", &c5,  NULL };
    struct TreeNode c3   = { 1003, "sshd-2", &c4,  NULL };
    struct TreeNode c2   = { 1002, "bash",   &c3,  NULL };
    struct TreeNode c1   = { 1001, "sshd-1", &c2,  &n1  };
    struct TreeNode root = { 1000, "sshd",   &c1,  NULL };

    print_processes(&root, 0, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1000: sshd
  1001: sshd-1
    1002: bash
      1003: sshd-2
  1011: bash
```

For the sake of reducing the `#include` lines to 1, I changed `pid_t` into `int`.